# Most liked photo

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to find the most liked photo in my DB. There are PHOTOS,LIKES,USERS tables. I tryed to find most liked photo and user who posted the picture with only LIKES and USERS and got an error.

```
SELECT 
    users.username,
    photo_id,
    COUNT(*) AS most_liked
FROM
    likes
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id=likes.user_id
GROUP BY
    photo_id
ORDER BY
    most_liked DESC
LIMIT
    1;
```

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ig_clone.users.username' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Can I do this with only 2 tables or should I use 3rd table as well?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems very clear and suggests a way to fix the problem.

Comment: You need to add the user name to your group by clause  Group by phto_id, users.username

Comment: Getting username is indeterministic here. It can be any username who has liked that photo. That is why MySQL is throwing error.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks. I thought that I was selecting a user who posted the photo, but user_id are the users who liked the photo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to to find most-liked-photos (using only the `likes` table) separately from actual photo information (from the `photos`) table - which is then joined to `users`. I assume your `photos` table has a `user_id` column.

```
SELECT
    users.username,
    photos.photo_id,
    photo_likes.like_count

FROM
    photos
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            photo_id,
            COUNT(*) AS like_count
        FROM
            likes
        GROUP BY
            photo_id
    ) AS photo_likes
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = photos.user_id

ORDER BY
    like_count DESC

LIMIT
    1
```